# Location Description

Tags: grammar, prepositions, locative

When I described the location of the shop, I preferred to use "upper side" phrase, but one of my friends advised me to use compass information.

My Sentence: `The shop is located in upper side of of Main road`

My friend Sentence: `The shop is located the north of Main road`

- Which one is better ?
- Is my sentence incorrect ?

Comment: It probably wouldn't be *the upper **side*** of a road/street unless the road ***crossed*** a steep slope (with buildings on one side significantly higher than the opposite side). Usually it would be the upper (or ***top***) ***end*** of the road. Note that ***upper*** and ***north*** don't necessarily correlate.

Comment: Unless the shop is located at the north pole, the description **north** is unambiguous. The sentence is missing a preposition though: "The shop is located **on** the north side of Main Road."